# Gurobi GRBModel and GRBmodel in C++

Tags: c++, linear-programming, gurobi

I am using Gurobi solver in a c++ interface. I need to use

```
int GRBgetBasisHead (GRBmodel *model, int *bhead)
```

I created my model with:

```
GRBModel model1 = GRBModel(env);
```

I get the following error

```
error: cannot convert ‘GRBModel*’ to ‘GRBmodel* {aka _GRBmodel*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int GRBgetBasisHead(GRBmodel*, int*)’
```

When I create my model with:

```
GRBmodel *model2 = NULL;
```

the instruction (int GRBgetBasisHead (GRBmodel *model, int *bhead)) works but the manipulation of the model is different from the previous declaration. Is there any way to relate the `model1` and `model2`?

Comment: I get the following error:  {error: cannot convert ‘GRBModel*’ to ‘GRBmodel* {aka _GRBmodel*}’ in initialization} for: {GRBmodel *p_model1 = &model1;}

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you have a typo there. It's `GRBModel`, not `GRBmodel` - note the capital "M".

**EDIT:**

There is no typo. The advanced simplex routines can only be called from the C API, where you are dealing with `GBRmodel`. There is currently no way of calling these methods from C++.

Comment: I though in the beginning the it is a typos but GRBgetBasisHead receives a pointer to a model of type GRBmodel and not GRBModel